# How to change application's top bar appearance in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, gtk

Alternative title: why in the world my dark themes look so bad?

I've installed a few themes for Xubuntu but some apps cannot have their top bar fully changed (and others can). In every single theme I've tried so far the white, terrible looking gradient stil exists. How can I modify it's appearance?

[image]

Comment: What was the theme selected in the screenshot? Arc?

Comment: @Anwar Exactly. But any dark skinn have the same white gradient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xubuntu needs two settings change to change the theme completely. What you changed in **Appearance** is just the gtk style. You didn't change the Window manager theme yet

To change that, follow these steps

1. Go to **Settings Manager**
2. Click on **Window Manager**
3. Then select the matching window manager theme style from **Style Tab**.

Here is a screenshot after I changed the window manager theme

[image: xubuntu window manager theme change settings]